# Weebly Lightbox/fancy box close button layered behind image Weebly

Tags: lightbox2, fancybox-3, weebly

Weebly Fancybox/Lightbox Mobile Issues- X layered behind image and Images too high

Can anyone assist with the following issues:

1- How can I make the close X button in fancybox/lightbox layer in front of the image? In mobile view the X is often partly or fully hidden behind the image and can't be clicked, this happens when the image is quite wide.

2. On mobile, the images in the fancybox/lightbox appear toward the top of the image screen on mobile, do you know how to centre these on the mobile screen?

Comment: Not possible to answer without seeing a live demo/page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.